# unity How to swipe jump motion using add force.

Tags: unity-game-engine, touch, swipe

I have a ball standing on a platform and i have written code so that every time i swipe up the ball jumps from one platform to another depending on the force of the swipe. At the moment my platforms are just placed in position by myself and i dont have a script for their random generation. The only script i have is on the player for swiping and moving forward.

Currently im making this motion by adding force in two directions, up and forward to create the projectile motion. Its working like its supposed too, but the motion is too slow. I want it to sort of move faster. Iwe tried playing with the forces as well as the mass of the ball. They do make a difference, but I still want the ball to move some what faster.

Is adding force the best way to do this? Or would you recommend a different way?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SwipeScript : MonoBehaviour {
public float maxTime;
public float minSwipeDist;

float startTime;
float endTime;

Vector3 startPos;
Vector3 endPos;
float swipeDistance;
float swipeTime;

// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{

    if (Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
        Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);

        if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
        {
            startTime = Time.time;
            startPos = touch.position;
        }
        else if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
        {
            endTime = Time.time;
            endPos = touch.position;

            swipeDistance = (endPos - startPos).magnitude;
            swipeTime = endTime - startTime;

            if (swipeTime < maxTime && swipeDistance > minSwipeDist)
            {
                swipe();
            }
        }
    }
}

public void swipe()
{
    Vector2 distance = endPos - startPos;

    if (Mathf.Abs(distance.y) > Mathf.Abs(distance.x))
    {
        Debug.Log("Swipe up detected");
        jump();
    }

}
private void jump()
{
    Vector2 distance = endPos - startPos;
    GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(new Vector3(0, Mathf.Abs(distance.y/5), Mathf.Abs(distance.y/5)));
}

private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.name == "Cube (1)") {
        Debug.Log("collision!");
        GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = Vector3.zero;
        GetComponent<Rigidbody>().angularVelocity = Vector3.zero;
    }
}
```

}

[image: why is the ball shadow so pixelated by the way?]

Comment: Just a quick off-topic tip: save your Rigidbody in `Start()` so you don't have to use GetComponent every time you want to use it, which isn't very optimized. It will also make your code cleaner. `Rigidbody rb; Start(){rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>(); }` and then use rb instead of GetComponent in the rest of the script.

You could, theoretically increase the timescale (`Time.timeScale = 2`) to make everything double the speed. But I do not recommend it. If you want the ball to move faster, you add more force and increase the drag. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-drag.html

Comment: If any answer solved your problem, please consider accepting it as the right one. _(Accepting an answer helps future visitors coming on this page)_

Answer (score 1):

I was writing my answer when I noticed @Fredrik comment: pretty much all he said was in what I wrote so I'll just skip it ! *(I also do not recommend increasing `Time.timeScale`)*

The other way you could move your ball would be using ballistic equations and setting your **RigidBody** to Kinematic. This way you will be able to control the ball speed through code using `RigidBody.MovePosition()` and still get `OnCollision[...]` events.

Also as a side note I do not recommend using `collision.gameObject.name` for collision object checking but rather tagging your cubes or even setting their layer to a specific one (but I guess this may be temporary code of yours ;) ).

Hope this helps,

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this is just scrapy code to get the feel for the project before I start coding properly, ideally I wouldnt be using oncollision but as you said tags with ontrigger. Just out of curiosity, why do you prefer the second one rather then the oncollision one. Secondly, neither of you said something like, getting the swipe input and then simply using that to edit the transform positions to some how look like projectile motion. Is there any reason why you guys didnt say something like that? Is it because its ugly? or that using addforce/rigidbody.moveposition are better? and why?

Comment: one more question, do you have any idea why my player shadow looks so pixelated? I have my build settings to android. does it have something to do with resolution etc or is there some inspector setting that i messed up?

Comment: About your first question: if you change the `transform.position` manually, the chances of messing with unity Physics are really high (for example you can easily miss an `OnTriggerEnter` / `OnCollisionEnter` event), this is why it's highly recommend (I could even say it's forbidden) to do so ;) About your second question: I remember someone asked it recently on SO, I guess you have to play with shadow settings (soft/hard, resolution, distance, etc...)

Answer (score 0):

Either pass ForceMode.VelocityChange as a second parameter to AddForce, or make sure you divide your vector by Time.fixedDeltaTime (which has the effect of multiplying it because Time.fixedDeltaTime will be less than 1).